# How does the Thai language express the instrumental?

Tags: syntax, grammar, cases, thai

In English and many European languages the instrumental is expressed with a preposition:

- I eat noodles *with* chopsticks.

(But "with" is not dedicated to this function and has other uses such as the comitative "I eat dinner *with* my parents.)

Another construction for the instrumental in English would be:

- I use chopsticks to eat noodles.

In languages with a case system, there is sometimes a specific instrumental case. In others, another case my do double duty for the instrumental, or one of those cases in combination with specific prepositions.

In Chinese, the construction I know is like the second English one, using 用 for "use" in a serial verb construction.

What does Thai use? I'm in Thailand but haven't found a way to ask my local friends that they get what I'm asking (-: I've been unable to successfully Google for it so far.

I think it may use เอา and maybe in a serial verb construction, so maybe a bit like Chinese? But maybe it's like English and has more than one way to express it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serial verb construction is the most common and least marked way of expressing the instrumental meaning. Among the verbs used in the first verb position include:

> - เอา (*ao*)
> - ใช้ (*chái*)
> - นำ (*nam*)

For example, as [quoted here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Su7xu4FXfEcC&pg=PA177):

> เขาใช้มีดตัดเนื้อ
>
> kăo chái mêet dtàt néua
>
> *he take knife cut meat*

There is also a version with ด้วย (*dûai*), which literally means "together with", but it is highly marked, and believed to be related to / calqued from Khmer. The word order parallels the English one `(VERB + DIRECT OBJECT + ด้วย / with + INSTRUMENT)`.

Comment: Independently verified at last [in my English for Thai speakers Duolingo course](https://www.duolingo.com/new-comment?fromLanguage=th&learningLanguage=en&sentenceId=d6a860c20f8dbe20b6334a2c371dfd4a) (since Thai for English speakers doesn't exist yet.)

Comment: Interestingly, I came across [another example in the same Duolingo course which uses "ด้วย"](https://www.duolingo.com/new-comment?fromLanguage=th&learningLanguage=en&sentenceId=f876c0f84d2ba6a4e3de5532f95f40d1).